# Are hudud punishments only applicable if the sin occurred within a Muslim state?

Tags: hudud

If a Muslim commits a major sin i.e adultery, homosexuality, etc. outside the territory of a Muslim state, can he/she be put to death if they confess to the sin when they return to the Islamic state? 
please provide proof of your answer and not base your answer on your rational understanding.

Comment: Brother, what are you doing? There is no Islamic state, your option is to repent and move on. People have committed much worse and repented. People that used to associate others with Allah repented and became strong believers. — And do not despair of Allahs mercy. This idea of looking for some Muslim “jurist” somewhere in the world so he can cut your head off is insane.

Comment: Salam Medi1Saif ive been blocked from asking questions. i know ive been a smart ### inshalah ill stop. can you pleas help me fix my questions so as to get unblocked. im not too sure what too do, also will try posting more appropriate questions in the futer. jazakhalakhairan salamunalakum

Comment: You cannot edit a question to change almost all of its content as this may render answers below inapplicable. I have rolled back your edits.

Comment: ive actually been blocked from asking more questions. any way you might be able to help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rulings (*hudūd*, Arabic: حدود) are not limited by where the actual crime took place. Long as there is evidence, a Muslim ruler may apply the punishment regardless of where or when the act was committed. From the hadith about Mā'iz ibn Malik in [Sahih Muslim 29/34](https://www.sunnah.com/muslim/29/34), when Mā'iz asked the Prophet ﷺ to purify him, the Prophet ﷺ asked him four questions:

1. The nature of the crime ("from what am I to purify you?").
2. The sanity of Mā'iz since a good number of *hudūd* do not apply to insane people ("asked if he had been mad").
3. The soberness of Mā'iz to ensure that his testimony is not the result of intoxication ("a person stood up and smelt his breath but noticed no smell of wine").
4. The final question was to validate the act ("have you committed adultery").

All questions were related to the self-incrimination and its context. However, there was not a single question about the context of the crime itself (where, when, etc.).

In another hadith, authenticated by [Al-Hākim An-Nisapūri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Hakim_Nishapuri) in his *Al-Mustadrak 'ala as-Sahihain* and by [Muhammad Nasiruddin al-Albani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_Nasiruddin_al-Albani) in *Sahīh al-Jāmi'*, the Prophet ﷺ provides the steps for anyone who is involved in any such act:

> عَنْ اِبْنِ عُمَرَ قَالَ: قَالَ رَسُولُ اَللَّهِ ﷺ: اِجْتَنِبُوا هَذِهِ اَلْقَاذُورَاتِ اَلَّتِي نَهَى اَللَّهُ تَعَالَى عَنْهَا فَمَنْ أَلَمَّ بِهَا فَلْيَسْتَتِرْ بِسِتْرِ اَللَّهِ تَعَالَى وَلِيَتُبْ إِلَى اَللَّهِ تَعَالَى, فَإِنَّهُ مَنْ يَبْدِ لَنَا صَفْحَتَهُ نُقِمْ عَلَيْهِ كِتَابَ اَللَّهِ عَزَّ وَجَلَّ
>
> Ibn 'Umar (RAA) narrated that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: "Avoid these filthy practices which Allah, the Almighty has prohibited. He who commits any of these, should conceal with Allah's Most High Veil (i.e. should not speak about it), and should turn to Allah, the Most High in repentance, for if anyone uncovers his hidden sins (to us), we shall inflict on him the punishment prescribed by Allah, the Al-Mighty."
>
> <sub>— [Bulugh al-Maram, Book 10, Hadith 1261](https://www.sunnah.com/urn/2115090)</sub>

These steps are:

1. Avoid such act in the first place.
2. If committed and no one knows, keep the act hidden, and repent to Allah.
3. If made public, the ruler has to carry the punishment through.

Comment: jazakhallah khairan for your response. how sure are you that this information is factulay correct, also if certain would you be able to direct the audience to a place where executions can be carried out swiftly for those whom their sins have been made public? may allah reward you for your efforts.

Comment: @Ahmed, I am not aware of any country that can be called an "Islamic state". My advice is that the person in question should seek Allah's forgiveness by repentance, not through seeking a punishment. Allah forgives all sins except _shirk_. Why despair of Allah's mercy?

Comment: what if its become public. how does one live with himself? how does one marry? hudud becomes a rahma on the person. there should be a way? soudia arabia, sudan, nigeria, brunai??  the person can do hijrah but it bound to come out somehow people get jealous many people do gheeba, just imagine if the person does well for him self and becomes well know, sum1 is gonna try take him down. huduud is better than suicide, after not being able to succede after repeated attempts suicide becoms verry tempting. suicide is jahanam 4 eva. not a good choice. so i say huduud is fard for that person.

Comment: plesae help audience come up witha practical sollution jazakhalakhairan

Comment: Also have azked a mufti about this he says hudood is limited to the territory of the state. Im not satisfied with his answer.

Comment: @Ahmed, The punishment has to be carried out by an authorized judge; it can be done neither by an unauthorized person nor by the person himself. There is no practical solution other than repentance. One who committed such acts should try to hide it as much as possible (even if it has become public already, then limit its publicity), and increase good deeds, prayers, and perform _hajj_ if possible. Allah's mercy is beyond one's imagination. Isn't it enough as a practical solution?

Comment: @III-AK-III Surely the location is a matter of disagreement amongst the scholars? How can a ruler have legal rights over citizens from another country? The first Hadith which you mention does not have the contextual knowledge of the person’s location. Given its language, it appears that the Prophet PBUH knew or it was taken for granted that this man was under his authority. For example, when Muslims were held captive in Mecca and the pagans signed a deal with the Prophet to send its runaway citizens back to them, the Prophet PBUH agreed to such a deal. This would apply more in the modern world

Comment: @III-AK-III Also I’m not sure why you’re responding to a person whose practically looking for a fatwa to end his life? Especially with an opinion that may lead his confused state to think he’s on the correct path? This is so reckless. Questions such as this should not be responded to and shut down.

Comment: Shadi doesnt your answer about the runaway citizens support my aim yes (fatwa to die) as it appears to demonstrate the prohet had authority over non citizens in sending them back?

Comment: @III-AK-III i kind of agree about the authorised judge part but but still not convinced as to being no practical solution other than repentance,

Answer (score 0):

based on my knowledge there is nothing to say that hadd punishment cannot be applied to such a person. unfortunately it appears the Muslim countries of today have little resemblance to a legitimate Islamic states. if you are addament on leaving this world through purification with hadd punishment then perhaps confessing in soudi arabia, iran or even some states in nigeria appear to enforce some aspects of sharia law.